# How to switch from one UIViewController to another?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem with switching from one viewcontroller to another.

Here is what I have :

In my "AppDelegate_iPad.m" :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    

    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    LoginViewController_iPad *loginView = [[LoginViewController_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    [window addSubview:loginView.view];


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

That works. Now I have a login button on that screen and when pressed it calles this :

```
- (IBAction)doPressLoginButton
{
    DebugLog(@"doPressLoginButton");

    MenuViewController_iPad *menuView = [[MenuViewController_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:menuView animated:YES];
    [menuView release];

}
```

The problem is that nothing happends. I assume I am missing the actual navigationconroller ?!

Hope that anyone can help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a UINavigationController instance variable in your app delegate. Then, make sure you synthesize it and release it in your dealloc method.

Your implementation of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` could look like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    

    // window is usually an IBOutlet
    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    LoginViewController_iPad *loginView = [[LoginViewController_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView];
    [loginView release];

    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Now you'll be able to use self.navigationController.

Comment: Regarding your comment about window being an IBOutlet. Well I know that but I work without the MainWindow.xib, so I create the window myself.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume I am missing the actual navigationconroller ?!

you are right. :D

`self.navigationController` returns nil if you don't set up an NavigationController.
And any messages send to `nil` object will be ignored.

If you only need switch from one to another.
using

```
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

instead.

Comment: Switching would be ok, but presentModalViewController throws an error : request for member 'presentModalViewController' in something not a structure or union